# How Spring MVC works with mybatis?

Tags: sql, maven, spring-mvc, mybatis

I am new to Spring MVC and i completed one crud operation using Spring MVC with JDBC template in Maven, now I am going to use of myBatis for same project.

But i don't know about myBatis , what is the advantage of using myBatis instead of JDBC and how it works with Spring MVC.

Comment: Why myibatis ? it was old technology. Use Hibernate

Comment: I am working in a company and they are telling to use myBatis only.

Comment: @Vinay Hegde *Why myibatis ? it was old technology.*. That stats on GitHub would suggest otherwise. https://github.com/mybatis/mybatis-3

Comment: @AlanHay I agree , In terms of simplicity ibatis is good , but Hibernate provides much more advanced cache , and no need to spend more time on sql.

Answer (score 0):

MyBatis has an official demo app called [JPetStore](https://github.com/mybatis/jpetstore-6) which is based on [Stripes](https://github.com/StripesFramework/stripes).
There are several user contributed variants and [this one](https://github.com/making/spring-jpetstore) is based on Spring MVC.

If you are using [Spring Boot](https://spring.io/projects/spring-boot), check out [this demo project](https://github.com/kazuki43zoo/mybatis-spring-boot-jpetstore) which uses [MyBatis Spring Boot Starter](https://github.com/mybatis/spring-boot-starter) to make configuration easier.